# Wake on LAN with MAAS stuck in commissioning (does not turn on the machine)

Tags: maas, wakeonlan

I have a MAAS cluster controller with two NIC (**eth0** - 193.51.236.0/24 - connected to public network and **p1p1** - 192.168.0.0/24 - used for private MAAS nodes). I use 5 physical machines HP compaq 6000 Pro. When I turn on one of these machines, it correctly does PXE boot from the MAAS cluster controller and in the MAAS console it is shown as "declared". There is a warning icon next to the hostname with error:

*This node does not have a power type set and MAAS will be unable to control it. Click 'Edit node' and set one.*

Also, it shows 0 CPU, Memory and disk space.

When, I update the power type to "Wake-on-LAN" with the correct MAC and save, I'm not able to commission the node. It does not turn on the machine and hangs on the "commissioning" status. I checked time is correctly set on the node (check in BIOS).

The WOL with the node works just fine, i.e., I can turn it on using:

`wakeonlan -i 192.168.0.255 00:23:24:0e:0d:e7`

from the MAAS cluster controller. I have to specify the `-i 192.168.0.255` since the default `255.255.255.255` does not do anything.

If I turn it on manually (e.g. using `wakeonlan`) it eventually goes into `ready` state and correctly detects CPU, Memory and disk space. Again, if I try to start the, it wont do anything, but if I power it on manually, it works just fine.

EDIT:

It seems that the problem is related to having two NICs - the magic packet is only sent over the eth1 (even though the cluster is correctly configured indicating p1p1 as the managed interface) which is incorrect (sudo tcpdump -i eth1 port 9 -vvvv -s0 -n). Submitted a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1343317

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution. The actual command used by MAAS to wakeonlan the machines is specified in a template file.

You just have to edit this template file:

```
sudo vim /etc/maas/templates/power/ether_wake.template
```

There will be a line with:

```
/usr/bin/wakeonlan $mac_address
```

Just change it to include the broadcast address of the network as you did in your command:

```
/usr/bin/wakeonlan -i 192.168.0.255 $mac_address
```

Comment: This is indeed what I did.

Comment: Did you find that out too? There is no documentation about it, I had to read the MAAS code to figure this out. Even though more than one year has passed, I thought it would be good to post the answer as it may help other people.

Comment: @HugoSadok , now there is a new problem, in 16.04 several files are moved or not even there anymore. For example WOL is not even an option anymore in MAAS 16.04. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3892683, didn't use 16.04 yet. But I gave up on MAAS... I was solving problem after problem and simply not using the exactly same architecture as proposed caused too much pain. Hope you find a solution.

Comment: @HugoSadok Out of curiosity what are u using now? I am trying to get openstack to work, but MAAS is giving me a really hard time

Answer (score 1):

It is not related to two NICs on Ubuntu 14.04! Using one NIC on MAAS cluster controller below!

It works from MAAS cluster controller with wakeonlan the node!

```
user@host:~$ wakeonlan 00:0b:db:78:07:33 
Sending magic packet to 255.255.255.255:9 with 00:0b:db:78:07:33
```

But not with juju bootstrap and the node in Ready status on MAAS!

```
user@host:~$ juju bootstrap
WARNING ignoring environments.yaml: using bootstrap config in file "/home/ron/.juju/environments/maas.jenv"
Launching instance
WARNING picked arbitrary tools &{"1.18.4-trusty-amd64" "http:    //192.168.2.2/MAAS/api/1.0/files/?key=6497d00c-2d4b-11e4-9ca7-00137273b6ca&op=get_by_key" "992e4244874ffec4af083cdeb58040420320f63ac6a3f7526c81d963fa4e53d6" %!q(int64=7389403)}
 - /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-995e00b4-1fe9-11e4-a6a3-00137273b6ca/
Waiting for address
Attempting to connect to eej3n.maas:22
Attempting to connect to 192.168.2.142:22
```

Comment: I don't get the answer, can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue!

You simply **must** set the MAC Address using UPPERCASE, so instead of `e4:1f:13:2d:8b:28` it **must** be `E4:1F:13:2D:8B:28`

Comment: So you are saying that `wakeonlan e4:1f:13:2d:8b:28` does nothing and `wakeonlan E4:1F:13:2D:8B:28` works?